# Create a 3D pillow using CSS

Tags: css, 3d

I would like to create a 3D pillow using CSS.

- I want to be able to spin it left, right, up, down and also rotate it from it's center by changing values in the CSS.
- I want it to look soft.
- I want to be able to add a background image to the pillow.

**Would this be possible using only CSS? If so, where can I learn? If not, do you have any suggestions?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using CSS to do that, sounds very difficult if it were possible.

Do a quick google search of 3d model viewers using javascript.

Then, either find or create a file that can be used with the 3d viewer.

.PLY files should work on most 3d model viewers, you may want to look into this file type.
http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/3D_file_format has a list of 3d file types.

To create some of these files you can either use a programming language you feel conformable with, which has libraries to help create the file, or perhaps use a model making program, like blender, which is most likely way more than you need.  **EDIT:** If you have access to a 3d scanner, you can use of those as well.

If you're creating the files using code, you may want to get meshlab, free software which allows you to look at some 3d file types, like .ply files.

**EDIT:** Or, a somewhat easier workaround would be to create you're own .gif files, or an animated image.  You could make one with a pillow rotating in on direction and another in a different direction, then have directional buttons around the image which change the image being shown.  Its not quite what you're asking for but it might be easier than creating a lighted, shaded 3d model of a pillow.

Comment: You can model the pillow in a 3D application (like Blender, as mentioned in the answer) and then display the 3D model using WebGL (but make sure the browsers Your users use support WebGL first). This can be implemented without any additional libraries, but it requires some work to write. You can find tutorial about WebGL here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL. This would give You most control and possible features.

Comment: However, it still may be enough just to fake 3d effect, like suggested in the answer. To achieve this kind of effect You may try to use a set of static images showing pillow from different angles. In this case, however, You would have to implement appropriate images display management anyway.